# Convert a Word document into an Excel sheet placing the text and Headings into separate cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Firstly, I am not a superuser but can definitely follow instructions so any help is very appreciated!

I have a word document with paragraphs defined by Headings:

[image: As in this picture]

I want to extract all the headings (numbers in the picture) and the text associated into separate cells and columns like this:

[image: Separate Cells]

I have no idea how to even start going about it!

I have tried converting the word doc to excel but the heading numbers keep being put into the same cell as the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the heading numbers to text by opening the VBA direct window (**Alt-F11** followed by **Control-G**), and typing:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
```

Now you can close VBA again and copy your text; it will have a Tab after each heading number which will (by default) paste it to different cells in Excel.

Don't save your Word document, if you still want to use the headings...